# Самая частая буква в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def checkio(text: str) -> str:

    mas= ''.join(sorted(text))
    coun = {}
    for i in mas:
      #if s in count:
         nums =mas.count(i)
         coun[nums]=i

    new_list = list(coun.keys())
    new_list.sort()

    return new_list # что возвращать ? 



    #replace this for solution


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(checkio("Hello World!"))

    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert checkio("Hello World!") == "l", "Hello test"
    assert checkio("How do you do?") == "o", "O is most wanted"
    assert checkio("One") == "e", "All letter only once."
    assert checkio("Oops!") == "o", "Don't forget about lower case."
    assert checkio("AAaooo!!!!") == "a", "Only letters."
    assert checkio("abe") == "a", "The First."
    print("Start the long test")
    assert checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000) == "a", "Long."
    print("The local tests are done.")
```

Дан текст, который содержит различные английские буквы и знаки препинания. Вам необходимо найти самую частую букву в тексте. Результатом должна быть буква в нижнем регистре.
При поиске самой частой буквы, регистр не имеет значения, так что при подсчете считайте, что "A" == "a". Убедитесь, что вы не считайте знаки препинания, цифры и пробелы, а только буквы.

Если в тексте две и больше буквы с одинаковой частотой, тогда результатом будет буква, которая идет первой в алфавите. Для примера, "one" содержит "o", "n", "e" по одному разу, так что мы выбираем "e".
P.S. Рассортировал словарь по ключам , где ключи количество одинаковых букв в строке, не совсем понимаю как извлечь значение

Comment: *Результатом должна быть буква в нижнем регистре* - ключ максимального значения в словаре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи нам может помочь класс `Counter` в модуле *collections*

```
from collections import Counter

def find_frequent_letter(text):
    text = str(text).lower() # Все переносим в нижний регистр
    ct = Counter(text)
    # У данного класса есть метод `most_common`
    # в котором указываем количество чаще повторяющихся элементов
    # в порядке убывания, но в твоем случае нужно найти максимальный
    # поэтому прописываем 1
    most_commons = ct.most_common(1)
    most_frequent = most_commons[0]
    return most_frequent[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = find_frequent_letter("HelLo WorLd! Well Done")
    print(r)
    # Output: 'l'
```

Но а если допустим мы не знаем про существование класса Counter, то можно написать следующий алгоритм:

```
def get_freq_letter(text):
    text = text.lower()
    result_dict = {}
    for letter in text:
        try:
            # Если наша буква уже есть в словаре, увеличиваем значение ее на 1
            result_dict[letter] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # Нашей буквы нет в словаре, добавляем ее
            result_dict[letter] = 1
    most_commons = sorted(
        result_dict.items(),
        key=lambda kv: kv[1],
        reverse=True
    )  # сортируем по количеству встречаний
    most_frequent = most_commons[0]
    return most_frequent[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = find_frequent_letter("HelLo WorLd! Well Done")
    print(r)
    # Output: 'l'
```

Comment: Спасибо , а подскажите как вернуть только символ без числа ?

Comment: Я щас обновлю ответ, поправлю и добавлю еще один способ решения

Comment: @Anthony Все, добавил

Comment: я думаю что там уже нужно писать регулярное выражение которая удаляет подобные символы, или же валидацию на функцию добавить, типа та же самое регулярное выражение только проверяющий есть ли в строке лишние знаки или нет, если они есть то просто не пускать работать с функцией итд.. Писать сценарии, просто так удалять эти символы не получиться)

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter
    
def checkio(text: str) -> str:
    often_used = Counter(filter(str.isalpha, text.lower()))
    return max(often_used, key=lambda x: (often_used[x], -ord(x)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].