# Самая частая буква в слове. Python

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
import re
def checkio(text: str) -> str:
    text1 = re.findall('[^\W]', text.lower())
    a = (''.join(text1))
    text2 = re.findall('[a-z]', a)
    a1 = (''.join(text2))
    return(Counter(a1).most_common(1)[0][0])

print(checkio("Hello World!"))          # == "l", "Hello test"
print(checkio("How do you do?"))        # == "o", "O is most wanted"
print(checkio("One"))                   # == "e", "All letter only once."
print(checkio("Oops!"))                 # == "o", "Don't forget about lower case."
print(checkio("AAaooo!!!!"))            # == "a", "Only letters."
print(checkio("abe"))                   # == "a", "The First."
print(checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000)) # == "a", "Long."
```

Как решить проблему если при "One" должно получиться "e", а при "abe" должна получиться "a"?

Задавали тот же вопрос вот здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036053/Самая-частая-буква-в-тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036053/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: И как сократить 2 регулярки до 1й?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно отсортировать результат не только по частоте, но ещё и по тому, какая буква идёт раньше в алфавите:

```py
return sorted(Counter(a1).items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0][0]
```

Тогда результат получается какой нужно:

```
l
o
e
o
a
a
a
```

P.S. Вернее, можно не сортировку, а минимум прямо брать, это чуть оптимальнее. Но тоже с тем же ключом:

```py
return min(Counter(a1).items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
```

Comment: Как я этого не понял, что порядок букв в алфавите должен быть учтен... Спасибо